# Convert Columns to ROW

Tags: plsql, oracle10g, pivot

I am stuck with this requirement -

I have some data in the format

[image]

(Entries now show data for both periods (Jan. 2011) and (Feb. 2011) on the same line as apposed to appearing separately).

At the end I need to print the data using dbms_output.put_line command.

I am using Oracle 10.2g.

Comment: SELECT  ce_id,ce_nm,tmp_nm,Month,
         row_number() OVER ( partition by Month  order by rownum) rn
  FROM  
  
  (

select d.ce_id,d.ce_nm,b.tmp_nm,to_char(c.log_ts,'MON.YYYY') Month , sum (c.total_enters) Enters
from v_ce_tmp a,ttmp b,mv_tmp_daily_traffic c,tce d
where a.tmp_id=c.tmp_id and 
   b.tmp_id=c.tmp_id and
      d.ce_id=a.ce_id and 
   c.log_ts between '01-Jan-2011' and '28-Feb-2011' and 
      a.ce_id=286
   
group by d.ce_id,d.ce_nm,to_char(c.log_ts,'MON.YYYY'),b.tmp_nm
Order by to_char(c.log_ts,'MON.YYYY') DESC
)

Answer (score 0):

Oracle 10g does not have a PIVOT function but you can convert the rows of data into columns using an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression. The basic syntax would be:

```
select d.id,
  d.site,
  d.entrance,
  sum(case when d.date = 'Jan.2011' then enters else 0 end) "Jan.2011",
  sum(case when d.date = 'Feb.2011' then enters else 0 end) "Feb.2011"
from
(
  select id, site, entrance, date, enters
  from yourdata
) d
group by d.id, d.site, d.entrance;
```

Note: you can replace the subquery with `yourdata` with your current query.